# Unwanted Email Italics

Tags: titles, italic, email

I'm trying to add an email address beneath the author of an article, but can't get latex to format it correctly. Latex italicizes the email address despite me not telling it to.

Maybe this isn't the best way to add an email address to a title?

Here's an example (with my full list of packages in case something there is causing problems).

Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[sorting=none,citestyle=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{titling}
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
  \posttitle{%
    \par\end{center}
    \begin{center}\large#1\end{center}
    \vskip0.8em}%
}

\linenumbers

\title{My Title}
\subtitle{My subtitle}
\author{Me \\ \href{mailto:my_email@email.gov}{\textrm{my\_email@email.gov}} }
\date{August 2021}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's due to the option `affil-it` passed to `authblk`. But do you need the package at all?

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks!